# Loopback Find is returning Empty

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

Database : Mongo 3.4+
NodeJS:v6.9.4
OS: Centos 7+

In mongo shell, following command return result,

```
    db.processticket.find({"parentProcessID": "5978ab9f82c56ec868d0d002"})
```

however, following code find/findOne returns empty result

```
 app.models.processticket.findOne({
                where: {"parentProcessID": "5978ab9f82c56ec868d0d002" }
            }, function(err, result) {
```

Comment: What is the value of `err`?

Comment: No error. Value is empty even when tried through loopback explorer.Is that because of mongo security ?

Comment: Same exact issue here, querying the find method with id returns the object but with any other parameter returns an empty array, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `strictObjectIDCoercion` flag in model definition file. [Reference](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/MongoDB-connector.html#strictobjectidcoercion-flag)

Comment: Use as '
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true,
    "strictObjectIDCoercion": true
  },......'

Answer (score 0):

Please wrap the value of `parentProcessID` in `ObjectId` function. Since mongo saves Id values as ObjectId in your where query you need to warp the value of your parentProcessID with ObjectId function. You can find `ObjectID` function in native mongodb module

```
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
```